# Using conditionals in a document that changes something in a class

Tags: documentclass-writing

A bit new to making document classes ..  so please forgive the newbie sins I have surely committed.

I am trying to make a `documentclass` that represents a Report that my organization uses.  I am trying to set a flag in the `.tex` document to define if the document is `final` or `draft` state.  In the corresponding .cls, I would then alter the title page, headers/footers/etc.

Within a single document, this is successful (this is `companyreport.cls`):

```
\LoadClass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{final}

\settoggle{final}{true}

\begin{document}
% Define a table layout for the title page.

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X |}
    \hline
    \includegraphics{titleimage.png} & 
    \iftoggle{final}{Final}{Draft} Report \newline Title \\
    \hline
    \null & Confidential to \newline Company \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}


\newpage
Project Team
Revision History 

\end{document}
```

If I put the above in a documentclass, and try to set the value of `final` from the `.tex`, it doesn't work.

Wandering the hallways of work, I'm wondering if this is the right approach, and if I should be using class options instead ... ?

Comment: A class option is defined for the standard classes and explained in every introduction; so should be known already. Setting up an extra command, will be a bit of extra learning for your users.

Comment: saying "doesn't work" makes it harder to help, it would be easier if your example was an example of the problem and you said what it did and what you want it to do, then people just have to run the supplied example with tracing to debug.

Comment: A `.cls` file should not contain `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.  If you want to redefine how the title looks, you should redefine the command `\maketitle` or `\@maketitle` or so in your classfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard document classes already define `draft` and `final` options. Either those are redefined or extended using `\DeclareOption` which makes the relevant toggle then.

`companyreport.cls`

```
\ProvidesClass{companyreport}
\LoadClass{report}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{final}


\DeclareOption{draft}{\togglefalse{final}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\toggletrue{final}}
\PassOptionsToClass{draft}{report}
\PassOptionsToClass{final}{report}

\ProcessOptions

\endinput
```

And the driver file: `companyreport.tex`

```
\documentclass[final]{companyreport}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


%\settoggle{final}{true}

\begin{document}
% Define a table layout for the title page.

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X |}
    \hline
    \includegraphics{titleimage.png} & 
    \iftoggle{final}{Final}{Draft} Report \newline Title \\
    \hline
    \null & Confidential to \newline Company \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}


\newpage
Project Team
Revision History 

\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot load the class and later pass options to it. On the other hand, you are passing the option `report` to the classes `article` and `report`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: True, confused the order of arguments of `\PassOptionsToClass`